# Any API endpoint for the date of closing the books

Tags: quickbooks-online

The [Preferences](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/preferences) endpoint does not return the date of closing the books. The date can be set in Company Settings > Advanced > Accounting > Close the books.

Does anyone know?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I assume you are aware that closing the books as of a specific date only protects prior transactions and does not create any new transaction? How do you plan to use the Closing date?

Comment: Our users will be prompted with a proper warning for syncing invoices before the date.